# Flexbox for Responsive Design and Images

Tags: responsive-design, flexbox

1. Is Flexbox a good tool to use for Responsive Design (or should I
   stick to grids)?
2. Can anyone share some information on working with images in Flexbox and why they may be handled differently than text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Flexbox for responsive grids no problem. Great example can be found here http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/grids/ if anything they could be better, but it really depends on your browser support.

From my experience in using Flexbox, I've not needed to handle images differently to text.